# TransactionScope in azure webjobs

Tags: azure, transactionscope, azure-webjobs

I have a webjob running in azure that is processing data sent to an event hub.

In the eventprocessor I want to save information to a SQL server. To make sure that everything is inserted correctly I want to use transactions.

When I run the code locally everything works perfect. But when running in Azure nothing happens, no error is thrown.
What I have read it should be possible to use TransactionScope. This example code below is not working.

```
  using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
                {
                    dataImportDao.StartProcessingMessage(mappedMessage);
                    scope.Complete();
                }
```

Any suggestions how to solve it or if I should go with a different approach is very appreciated.

Comment: Is the code working without transaction and what is in StartProcessingMessage?

Comment: Yes, working in azure without the transactionscope. 
Working locally with the transactionscope as well.

StartProcessingMessage is a method for storing data in a SQL azure db.

Comment: Are you using only one db or multiple? If only one, you are better to avoid the transaction scope. When you have multiple dbs, are they all in the cloud? If not your scenario is not supported: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-transactions-overview/

Comment: I have only one db in the cloud. What is the best practice to update only 1 db but many tables in a transaction if you recommend to avoid the transactionscope.